# Collapse views like FAB with CollapsingToolbarLayout inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What attribute should be added in order for a view to behave like FAB that shrinks upon scroll up and collapsing a `Toolbar` that is inside `CoordinatorLayout`? Can you shrink the `ImageView` here with just XML attributes?

[image]